# Display all the values for every date in JSON

Tags: ruby, json, haml

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "groups" : [
      {
        "values": "21",
        "date": "2013-02-22"
      },
      {
        "values": "25",
        "date": "2013-02-22"
      },
      {
        "values": "20",
        "date": "2013-02-22"
      },
      {
        "values": "19",
        "date": "2013-02-22"
      },
      {
        "values": "42",
        "date": "2013-02-10"
      },
      {
        "values": "30",
        "date": "2013-02-10"
      },
      {
        "values": "11",
        "date": "2013-02-10"
      }

    ]
}
```

I have the values and the date already extracted in a Ruby Class. I want to find the "highest" and "lowest" value for every date. How do I do that?

Also I want to create parallel arrays for the same. For instance:

```
low = [12, 22, 11, 45]
high = [34, 50, 15, 60]
dates = ["2013-02-22", "2013-02-10", "2013-02-06", "2013-02-01"]
```

I would also like to display all the values for every date.

Could someone please give me some direction for this?

Comment: What have you tried? The [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) function is super helpful here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important to give us minimal input data, the expected output, and the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem you're seeing. That last part, the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem helps us NOT try everything possible but focus on how you're attacking the problem. As is, it seems like you haven't tried and want us to try for you, or explain how to do it, neither of which are how SO works.

Comment: When you give an example in a question (generally a very good thing to do) it is important that the input be valid Ruby objects. As you know, JSON objects are strings, so you need to add single quotes `'{...}'`, or use `%s[...]` or a heredoc. Also, you should assign all input values to variables, so they can be referenced in answers and comments without having to define them. For example, `str = `'{...}'`.

Answer (score 1):

If `str` is your JSON string:

```
require 'json'
arr = JSON.parse(str)["groups"]
  #=> [{"values"=>"21", "date"=>"2013-02-22"},
  #    {"values"=>"25", "date"=>"2013-02-22"},
  #    {"values"=>"20", "date"=>"2013-02-22"},
  #    {"values"=>"19", "date"=>"2013-02-22"},
  #    {"values"=>"42", "date"=>"2013-02-10"},
  #    {"values"=>"30", "date"=>"2013-02-10"},
  #    {"values"=>"11", "date"=>"2013-02-10"}] 

by_date = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) { |g,h|
  h[g["date"]] << g["values"].to_i }
  # => {"2013-02-22"=>[21, 25, 20, 19], "2013-02-10"=>[42, 30, 11]}

dates = by_date.keys
  #=> ["2013-02-22", "2013-02-10"]     
min_vals, max_vals = *by_date.map { |_,vals| vals.minmax }
  #=> [[19, 25], [11, 42]] 
min_vals
  #=> [19, 25] 
max_vals
  #=> [11, 42]
```

The method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) takes an argument that is the initial value of the object that will be constructed and returned by the method. It's value is given by the second block variable, `h`. I made that argument an empty hash with a default value given by the block:

```
{|h,k| h[k] = []}
```

What is the "default value"? All it means is that if the hash `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns an empty array. Let's see how that works here.

Initially, `h #=> {}` and `each_with_object` sets the first block variable, `g` equal to the first value of `arr`:

```
g = {"values"=>"21", "date"=>"2013-02-22"}
```

and block calculation is performed:

```
h[g["date"]] << g["values"].to_i
  #=> h["2013-02-22"] << 21
```

Since `h` does not have a key `"2013-02-22"`, `h["2013-02-22"]` is first set equal to the default value, an empty array:

```
h["2013-02-22"] = []
```

then

```
h["2013-02-22"] << 21
  #=> [21] 
h #=> {"2013-02-22"=>[21]}
```

When the next value of `arr` is passed to the block:

```
g = {"values"=>"25", "date"=>"2013-02-22"}
```

and `h` is as above. So now the block calculation is:

```
h[g["date"]] << g["values"].to_i
  #=> h["2013-02-22"] << 25
  #=> [21, 25] 
h #=> {"2013-02-22"=>[21, 25]}
```

The default value is not used this time, as `h` has a key `"2013-02-22"`.

One other thing may require explanation: the "splat" `*` in:

```
min_vals, max_vals = *by_date.map { |_,vals| vals.minmax }
```

We see that:

```
by_date.map { |date, vals| vals.minmax }
  #=> [[19, 25], [11, 42]]
```

If `*by_date.map { |date, vals| vals.minmax }` is on the right side of an equality, the splat causes the two elements of `[[19, 25], [11, 42]]` are assigned to variables on the left side of the equality using *parallel assignment*. The weird and wonderful [splat operator](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) needs to be in every Rubiest's bag of tricks.

Since I'm not using `date` in the block calculation, I've drawn attention to that by replacing `date` with the local variable `_`.

**Edit:** To answer the question you posted in a comment, if:

```
id   = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4]
high = [100,100,100,90,90,100,100]
low  = [20,20,20,10,10,30,40]
```

and I understand your question correctly, you could first compute:

```
indices = id.each_with_index.to_a.uniq(&:first).map(&:last)
  #=> [0, 3, 5, 6]
```

Then the three arrays you want are:

```
id.values_at(*indices)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
high.values_at(*indices)
  #=> [100, 90, 100, 100] 
low.values_at(*indices)
  #=> [20, 10, 30, 40]
```

Comment: Excellent. Well done. Just what I'd have posted. `by_date.map{ |k, v| [k, v.minmax] }.to_h` is also useful.

Comment: Cary, thanks for the answer. It really helped. What if I already have the high/low values in the json and I'm able to create an array with it? Say, I have, `high = [100,100,100,90,90,100,100]   low = [20,20,20,10,10,30,40]`. Also I have an identifier for a group of elements. `id=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4]`. How do I split this based on the identifier? I want the result to be `high = [100, 90,100,100] low = [20, 10, 30, 40] id = [1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Probably best to post another question.

Comment: Cary, I have edited the above comment to be more specific. Do you get my question ?

Comment: I just saw your comment but have to leave. I'll address it later today.

Comment: doesey, my apologies for the delay in answering the question you posted in the comment. I answered that with an edit to my answer. Please let me know if I misunderstood what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) `:date` and iterate through the dates. Then create an array of `:values` in the group.

Then use [`minmax`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) to get the proper values and [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose) the final array to get your arrays and assign to dates, low and high.

```
json = {
  "groups": [
    { "values": "21", "date": "2013-02-22" },
    { "values": "25", "date": "2013-02-22" },
    { "values": "20", "date": "2013-02-22" },
    { "values": "19", "date": "2013-02-22" },
    { "values": "42", "date": "2013-02-10" },
    { "values": "30", "date": "2013-02-10" },
    { "values": "11", "date": "2013-02-10" }
  ]
}

dates, low, high = json[:groups].group_by { |g| g[:date] }.map do |date, grouped|
  values = grouped.map { |group| group[:values] }
  [date, *values.minmax]
end.transpose
# => => [["2013-02-22", "2013-02-10"], ["19", "11"], ["25", "42"]] 

dates
# => ["2013-02-22", "2013-02-10"]
low
# => ["19", "11"]
high
# => ["25", "42"]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland I understand that but I believe someone new to a language have to be always reading the documentation and try all methods in answers to see what happens and learn from that.