# How can I get the count of overlapping ranges in sorted order?

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

Suppose I have an array of sorted inclusive ranges:

```
a = [1012..1014, 1016..1020, 1017..1022, 1021..1035, 1040..1080]
```

I want as output an array of arrays, each of whose first element is a range and second element its overlapping count, like this:

```
[[1012..1014, 1], [1016..1016, 1], [1017..1020, 2], [1021..1022, 2], [1023..1035, 1], [1040..1080, 1]]
```

For example, the range `1017..1020` is included in two ranges `1016..1020` and `1017..1022`, so its count would be two.

Comment: Are they all inclusive ranges (`..`, not `...`)?

Comment: the naive way to to create a hash and than check this hash.

Comment: @sawa Yes they all inclusive ranges.

Comment: Although this is not a big issue, it is not clear what you mean by "sort" in the input. How would `[1..4, 2..3]` be sorted? (The sense for sort in the output is clear.)

Comment: Can you explain bit more, i am clear with your example which you gave like 1017..1020 is included in two range 1016..1020 and 1017..1022 this can be done. but not clear with your question. As    a = [1012..1014, 1016..1020, 1017..1022, 1021..1035, 1040..1080] where independent range does not come in between any range so how you are giving output like  [[1012..1014, 1], [1016..1016, 1], [1017..1020, 2], [1021..1022, 2], [1023..1035, 1], [1040..1080, 1]]  so can you explain me

Comment: Your output [[1012..1014, 1]] is correct from where you getting [1016..1016, 1], [1017..1020]  are the ranges which is not available in your given range "a"

Comment: @sawa the input ranges will be sorted with its first item like 1012, 1014 etc.But I want output to be in sorted order and does not include the overlapping ranges.

Comment: @GouravNaik As you can see 1016 is included only in one range and from 1017 to 1020 there are two overlapping ranges(1016..1020, 1017..1022 ) so I want to break the ranges in such a way so they does not overlap and at the same time show me how many  ranges are included within that particular interval(range).which is in this case 2.

Comment: Assuming my understanding is correct, I think the following would be a fairly precise statement of the question: "Given an array `a` of ranges whose starting values are increasing, obtain an array `b` of increasing, non-overlapping ranges such that the ranges of `b` collectively cover the same numbers that are collectively covered by the ranges in `a` and each range in `b` is the largest range of numbers that are all covered by the same ranges in `a`. Lastly, convert each range in `b` to an array containing the range and the number of ranges in `a` that cover all the numbers in the range."

Comment: I did a small edit to add a reference to an explanation of `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=Set.new }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def range_info(a)
  covered_by = a.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=Set.new }) { |r,h|
    r.each { |n| h[n] << r } }
  a.flat_map { |r| r.to_a }.
    uniq.
    slice_when { |b,c| c > b+1 }.
    flat_map { |r| r.to_a.slice_when { |b,c| covered_by[b] != covered_by[c] } }.
    flat_map { |enum| enum.to_a.map { |a| [a.first..a.last, covered_by[a.first].size] } }
end
```

**Example**

```
a = [1012..1014, 1016..1020, 1017..1022, 1021..1035, 1040..1080]

range_info(a)
  #=> [[1012..1014, 1], [1016..1016, 1], [1017..1020, 2], [1021..1022, 2],
  #    [1023..1035, 1], [1040..1080, 1]]
```

**Explanation**

First create the hash `covered_by` with keys equal to numbers that are covered by at least one range in `a`, where `covered_by[n]` equals the set of all ranges in `a` that cover key `n`:

```
covered_by = a.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=Set.new }) { |r,h|
  r.each { |n| h[n] << r } }
  #=> {1012=>#<Set: {1012..1014}>, 1013=>#<Set: {1012..1014}>,
  #    ...
  #    1016=>#<Set: {1016..1020}>, 1017=>#<Set: {1016..1020, 1017..1022}>,
  #    ...
  #    1079=>#<Set: {1040..1080}>, 1080=>#<Set: {1040..1080}>}
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614343/display-all-the-values-for-every-date-in-json) for an explanation of `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }`, which is similar to `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=Set.new }`.

Next, obtain an array of increasing non-overlapping ranges that cover the same numbers that are covered by one or more ranges in `a`:

```
arr = a.flat_map { |r| r.to_a }.uniq.slice_when { |b,c| c > b+1 }
  #=> [1012..1014, 1016..1035, 1040..1080]
```

Next, break each of the ranges in `arr` into enumerators that will generate arrays of consecutive numbers that are covered by the same ranges in `a`:

```
b = arr.flat_map { |r| r.to_a.slice_when { |b,c| covered_by[b] != covered_by[c] } }
  #=> [#<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fd1ea854558>:each>,
  #    #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fd1ea8543c8>:each>,
  #    #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fd1ea854238>:each>]
```

We can see the elements of `b` by converting them to arrays:

```
b.map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[[1012, 1013, 1014]],
  #    [[1016], [1017, 1018, 1019, 1020], [1021, 1022],
  #     [1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 1031, 1032, 1033,
  #      1034, 1035]],
  #    [[1040, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1049, 1050,
  #      1051, 1052, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1057, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1061,
  #      1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1070, 1071, 1072,
  #      1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078, 1079, 1080]]]
```

Lastly, `flat_map` these arrays to arrays containing a range and the number of ranges in `a` that cover all the elements of the range:

```
c = b.flat_map { |enum| enum.to_a.map { |a| [a.first..a.last, covered_by[a.first].size] } }
  #=> [[1012..1014, 1], [1016..1016, 1], [1017..1020, 2], [1021..1022, 2],
  #    [1023..1035, 1], [1040..1080, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this problem.  It may not be efficient - *complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>)* - nonetheless, it is a solution.

My approach to find whether a range is sub-range of another range is to do following steps:

1. Convert both ranges to array and join then using `Array#|` operator
2. Sort the array obtained by combining the two ranges.
3. If one range is sub-range of another, then, the range that includes the sub-range will be equal to combined sorted array when converted to array using `to_a`.

Here is an illustration:

```
r1 = 2..3
r2 = 1..4

p a = r1.to_a | r2.to_a
#=> [2, 3, 1, 4]
p a = a.sort
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
p a == r1.to_a
#=> [1,2,3,4] == [2,3] 
#=> false
p a == r2.to_a
#=> [1,2,3,4] == [1,2,3,4]
#=> true
```

Based on the above approach, here is the complete code.  Although I am not sure that example list of ranges given in the question has any overlapping ranges, hence, I have taken example of my own.

```
h = {}
r_a = [1016..1020, 1017..1020, 1021..1035, 1040..1080]
r_a.each {|r| h[r] = 1}

(0...r_a.length).each do |i|
    (0...r_a.length).each do |j|
        if (i != j)
            range_outer = r_a[i]
            range_inner = r_a[j]

            first,*rest,last = (range_outer.to_a | range_inner.to_a).to_a.sort
            combined_range = Range.new(first, last)

            if range_inner == combined_range
                h[range_outer] += 1 
            end
        end
    end
end
p h
#=> {1016..1020=>1, 1017..1020=>2, 1021..1035=>1, 1040..1080=>1}
```

Comment: Yes this is the correct one, but op wants output something different which i cant recognize.. i have given upvote

Comment: @GouravNaik OP's example range `1017..1020` is not present in the array `a` - the values of `a` if processed shows no overlapping ranges.  That's why I picked up one range that did overlap as per the example in question

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works under limited occasions: when the minimum value of a range and the maximum value of a range are never identical. (I.e., if there is `x..100`, then there is no `100..y`. Also there is no `z..z`.)

```
break_points = a.flat_map{|r| [r.min - 1, r.min, r.max, r.max + 1]}.uniq.sort
a.flat_map do
  |r|
  break_points
  .select{|i| r.min <= i and i <= r.max}
  .each_slice(2)
  .map{|min, max| min..max}
end
.group_by(&:itself)
.map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}
```

Comment: I have no access to a Ruby interpreter these days, and have not tested the code above. It may have bugs, and is not a general answer. Any comments or another answer that improves this answer are welcome.

Comment: there are bugs, first is in your select statement where you gave .select{|i|  r.min <= i and i < = r.max}  there is space between < = and each slice wont work for ranges. As i cant edit i just pointed out mistakes i think you should remove this answer, as you have high reputed points sorry if i am wrong

Comment: @GouravNaik Thanks for pointing out the space mistake. I corrected it. I don't get what you mean by slice not working for ranges. I am using slice on an array (of ranges). I don't get why you think I should remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to test all subranges from the supplied ranges, you could try something like this (only accounts for subranges starting from the min value of each original range):

```
a = [1012..1014, 1016..1020, 1017..1022, 1021..1035, 1040..1080]
test_inputs = a.each_with_object([]) do |original, expanded| 
  original.size.times.each{ |i| expanded << Range.new(original.min, original.min+i) }
end

output = test_inputs.each_with_object([]) do |input, result|
  appears = a.select{|x| x.min <= input.min}.select{|x| x.max >= input.max}.count
  result << [input, appears]
end
```

Comment: What `test_inputs` you have given is different from my input.In my input I am giving ranges which are overlapping like 1016..1020, 1017..1022. Can you please suggest how can I get the desired result with the input as a = [1012..1014, 1016..1020, 1017..1022, 1021..1035, 1040..1080]

Comment: I get compilation error at `a.select` as `a` is not defined in your code.  Also, I did not get any output - how to get hold of `result` outside the block.  Can you share what output you are getting?

Comment: @WandMaker I misunderstood the question originally, and thought that the test inputs were provided separately.  `a` , in this case is the original supplied array of ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to solve your problem. Let

```
a = [1012..1014, 1016..1020, 1017..1022, 1021..1035, 1040..1080]
```

**Step 1:** Flatten this array, then count each element

```
b = a.map(&:to_a).inject(:+).sort.group_by{|i| i }.map{|k,v| [k,v.count] }

# => [[1012, 1], [1013, 1], [1014, 1], [1016, 1], [1017, 2], [1018, 2], [1019, 2], [1020, 2], [1021, 2], [1022, 2], [1023, 1], ...
```

**Step 2:** Add nil as break points

```
c = b.each_with_index do |e, i| 
  if e.nil? || b[i+1].nil? then next end
  if b[i][0] + 1  != b[i+1][0] || b[i][1] != b[i+1][1] then b.insert(i+1,nil) end
end 

# => [[1012, 1], [1013, 1], [1014, 1], nil, [1016, 1], nil, [1017, 2], [1018, 2], [1019, 2], [1020, 2], [1021, 2], [1022, 2], nil, [1023, 1], ...
```

**Step 3:** Split obtained array by break points and group them to ranges

```
d = c.split{|e| e.nil?}.map{|e| [(e.first[0]..e.last[0]), e.first[1]]}

# => [[1012..1014, 1], [1016..1016, 1], [1017..1022, 2], [1023..1035, 1], [1040..1080, 1]]
```

### Update:

Since split is a method from Rails, so I have an alternative with pure Ruby.

**Step 1:** same as above

**Step 2:** Split the array into small groups as below

```
c = []
j = 0
b.each_with_index do |e, i| 
  if c[j].nil? then c[j] =[] end
  c[j] << b[i]
  if b[i+1] && (b[i][0] + 1 != b[i+1][0] || b[i][1] != b[i+1][1]) then j+=1 end
end

# p c => [
#          [[[1012, 1], [1013, 1], [1014, 1]], 
#          [[1016, 1]], 
#          [[1017, 2], [1018, 2], [1019, 2], [1020, 2], [1021, 2], [1022, 2]], 
#           ...
#        ]
```

**Step 3:** Convert each group to a range

```
d = c.map{|e| [(e.first[0]..e.last[0]), e.first[1]]}

# => [[1012..1014, 1], [1016..1016, 1], [1017..1022, 2], [1023..1035, 1], [1040..1080, 1]]
```